# How do I customize django allauth sign up forms to look the way I want?

Tags: django, forms, django-allauth

How do I make a registration form without using this code

```
<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup'}">
  {% csrf_token %}   {{ form.as_p }}   {% if redirect_field_value %} <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />   {% endif %} <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} »</button>
</form>
```

Here is a small snippet of the custom sign up html

```
<div class="group-35">
          <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup'}">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="overlap-group-container-1">
            <input class="overlap-group1 border-1px-dove-gray -applesystemuifont-regular-normal-black-20px" type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"/>
            <input class="overlap-group2 border-1px-dove-gray -applesystemuifont-regular-normal-black-20px" type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="overlap-group">
            <input class="rectangle border-1px-dove-gray -applesystemuifont-regular-normal-black-20px" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          </div>
```

This code was generated using anima and I want to use input fields to sign up the user. So from this snippet I'd want to sign the user up with the first name, last name and email they entered in the input fields.

Comment: Why do you not want to use that specific code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see why you don't want to use that specific code snippet but if you don't mind using it you can just override the form that django allauth uses to add fields for first name and last name (allauth by default includes email)

In settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'yourapp.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

In yourapp/forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Now the signup form should include both of these new fields as long as you use form.as_p

If you have a reason you don't want to use that code snippet please let me know and I can update my answer

Comment: This doesn't work as it causes a circular import: `"cannot import name 'SignupForm' from partially initialized module 'allauth.account.forms' (most likely due to a circular import)`

Answer (score 0):

if you have error in a comments above

```
This doesn't work as it causes a circular import: "cannot import name 'SignupForm' 
from partially initialized module 'allauth.account.forms' (most likely due
to a circular import)
```

You should change django forms namespace, example:

```
# Importing django.forms under a special namespace because of my old mistake
from django import forms as d_forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm


class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    first_name = d_forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = d_forms.CharField(required=True)
```

And after that you easy replace default form to your's

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'users.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
```

As result:
[image: result code above]